# Can you specify what JSP page to include based on the request URL?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am trying to learn some JEE development.  Suppose I am building a website whose pages have a lot of common HTML code.  I want to avoid duplicating common HTML code for every page I create. Philosophically, there seem to be 2 ways of doing this.

1. Inheritance - Have every page "inherit" from a common template, only providing HTML code that will be "injected" into appropriate holes in the parent.  Django actually supports this.
2. Composition - Compose page by including other pre-defined html snippets into your page.

These aren't mutually exclusive.  Ideally, you could inherit from a parent template that defines the basic skeleton, but the code you inject into the parent could be composed of several different HTML snippets.

The problem is that JSP seems to only really support the latter method with:

```
<%@ include file="header-navigation.jsp" %>
<jsp:include page="/header-navigation.jsp"/>
```

I could implement "inheritance," if I was able to set some parameter on my servlet so that I can include pages dynamically:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <header>...commong header code...</header>
        <jsp:include page="/snippets/{view}/>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is still composition, but from the code's perspective, a servlet can set the "view" parameter knowing it will be injected into the overall skeleton, thereby achieving some form of template "inheritance."  Is this possible or even adviseable?

Another option would be to include controller logic inside a base.jsp file, but this seems very smelly.

```
<% if(view="aboutme") { %><%@ include file="aboutme.jsp" %><% } %>
<% if(view="aboutme") { %><jsp:include file="aboutme.jsp" %><% } %>
```

The first one seems pretty crazy, since this is a static include, and would result in gigantic JSP .class files that contained content from all pages.  The second one still seems iffy, and you still have to hardcode "aboutme.jsp"...

Please give some guidance on which avenue to pursue from here!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your pursuit is the same of thousand of other and the reply is not to use JSP.

There are many framework created specifically to render dynamic web content, still some basic knowledge of JSP and servlet is much useful to learn them.

I would consider JSF and Vaadin if you want to keep all development in java.

Then there is the possibility to build the server login in java (expecially with REST) and use popular javascript framework for the UI (like Angular or React).

If I were you I would first start with JSF because it builds up from JSP (expecially  the EL language).